# Cannot convert CLLocationCoordinate2D to (CLLocationCoordinate2D)

Tags: ios, swift, contains

I have a problem with my code. 
I get this error message:

> Cannot convert value of type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' to expected argument type '(CLLocationCoordinate2D) throws -> Bool'

```
if(locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates && isDriving){
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = locationManager.location?.coordinate else { return }
        Map.setCenter(locValue, animated: true)
        Map.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: locValue, latitudinalMeters: 75, longitudinalMeters: 75), animated: true)

        if !locations.contains(where: locValue) { //<- ERROR
            locations.append(locValue);
            NSLog("%f %f -> Gesamt: %d", locValue.latitude, locValue.longitude, locations.count);
            let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &locations, count: locations.count);
            Map.addOverlay(polyline);
        }
    }
```

locations:

```
var locations = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CLLocationCoordinate2D` does not conform to `Equatable`.

You have to compare both `latitude` and `longitude` in the `where` closure

```
if !locations.contains(where: {$0.latitude == locValue.latitude && $0.longitude == locValue.longitude}) { ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D : Equatable { 
    static public func ==(left: CLLocationCoordinate2D, right: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Bool {
        return left.latitude == right.latitude && left.longitude == right.longitude
    } 
}
```

---

```
if !locations.contains(locValue){  

}
```

For array to use `contains` , elements need to conform to `Equatable`  and since `CLLocationCoordinate2D` doesn't conform , then error fix needs you to add a where clause to specify how the comparison will be like